# Determine Number of Visits and Length of Stay by Client

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2016, ms-access-2016

I have a set of Client Records which only have ClientID and ServiceDate

I want to determine the Number of Visits and the Length of Stay of each Visit

I have Created some code in MS Access and Read Several of the similar questions recommended in the search of this question and other suggestions returned from Google searches

Current Code:

```
SELECT 
  a.Client, 
  a.ServiceDate, 
  DateAdd ( "d", -1, a.ServiceDate ) AS [Prior], 
  DateAdd ( "d", 1, a.ServiceDate ) AS [Next], ( SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Services_Table b
WHERE a.Client = b.Client 
      AND DateAdd ( "d", -1, a.ServiceDate ) = b.ServiceDate ) AS [Index]
FROM Services_Table AS a
ORDER BY a.Client, a.ServiceDate;
```

Input Data:

```
Client  ServiceDate
1   8/4/2018
1   8/5/2018
1   8/6/2018
6   7/11/2018
6   7/12/2018
6   7/17/2018
6   7/18/2018
6   7/19/2018
6   7/30/2018
6   7/31/2018
6   8/1/2018
6   8/2/2018
15  1/13/2019
15  1/14/2019
5   9/13/2018
5   9/14/2018
5   9/15/2018
```

Current Output:

```
Clt ServiceDate Prior           Next          Index
1   8/4/2018    8/3/2018    8/5/2018    0
1   8/5/2018    8/4/2018    8/6/2018    1
1   8/6/2018    8/5/2018    8/7/2018    1
5   9/13/2018   9/12/2018   9/14/2018   0
5   9/14/2018   9/13/2018   9/15/2018   1
5   9/15/2018   9/14/2018   9/16/2018   1
6   7/11/2018   7/10/2018   7/12/2018   0
6   7/12/2018   7/11/2018   7/13/2018   1
6   7/17/2018   7/16/2018   7/18/2018   0
6   7/18/2018   7/17/2018   7/19/2018   1
6   7/19/2018   7/18/2018   7/20/2018   1
6   7/30/2018   7/29/2018   7/31/2018   0
6   7/31/2018   7/30/2018   8/1/2018    1
6   8/1/2018    7/31/2018   8/2/2018    1
6   8/2/2018    8/1/2018    8/3/2018    1
15  1/13/2019   1/12/2019   1/14/2019   0
15  1/14/2019   1/13/2019   1/15/2019   1
```

Desired Result:

```
Clt Start           End     Length
1   8/4/2018    8/6/2018      3
5   9/13/2018   9/15/2018     3
6   7/11/2018   7/12/2018     2
6   7/17/2018   7/19/2018     3
6   7/30/2018   8/2/2018      4
15  1/13/2019   1/14/2019     2
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The logic is vastly different between Access and sql server. This type of problem is known as "gaps and islands". There are hundreds and hundreds of examples all over SO and everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by identifying the starts:

A start is a date where there's no consecutive previous date, so:

```
SELECT Client, ServiceDate
FROM Services_Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Services_Table s WHERE s.Client = t.Client AND s.ServiceDate = DateAdd("d", -1, t.ServiceDate))
```

Similarly, we can identify the ends:

```
SELECT Client, ServiceDate
FROM Services_Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Services_Table s WHERE s.Client = t.Client AND s.ServiceDate = DateAdd("d", 1, t.ServiceDate))
```

Then, we can join the starts and the ends together, and select the end date that's closest to the start:

```
SELECT Start.Client, Start.ServiceDate As Start, Min(End.ServiceDate) As End, Min(End.ServiceDate) - Start.ServiceDate As Length
FROM
(
    SELECT Client, ServiceDate
    FROM Services_Table t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Services_Table s WHERE s.Client = t.Client AND s.ServiceDate = DateAdd("d", -1, t.ServiceDate))
) Start
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Client, ServiceDate
    FROM Services_Table t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Services_Table s WHERE s.Client = t.Client AND s.ServiceDate = DateAdd("d", 1, t.ServiceDate))
) End ON (Start.Client = End.Client AND Start.ServiceDate <= End.ServiceDate)
GROUP BY Start.Client, Start.ServiceDate
```

Comment: Erik, Thank You Very Much works perfectly.  Just had to make 1 adjustment to Length by adding 1. In my case, I wanted Length to include both the Start Date and End Date (Partial Days) in Many, if Not Most, Cases the Length of Stay would be as you Calculated. I appreciate your Complete Explanation and Extremely Quick Response.  Steve